# Does the entropy of a real gas increase or decrease as compared to the entropy of ideal gas when the gas compartment is expanded so $V_f > V_i$

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas

so i know the derived equation for change in entropy of a real gas but im struggling to understand how to compare that to the change in entropy for an ideal gas to answer the above question

Comment: Please specify how the volume increases. Is it at  constant temperature, constant pressure, or some other process?

Comment: I support Chet Miller's answer. He proved it for both constant temperature and constant pressure. My intuition was apparently incorrect. I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivative of entropy with respect to pressure for an arbitrary substance is given by $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V$$For an ideal gas, this reduces to $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T=\frac{R}{V}$$What is it for a van der Waals gas? I get:$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T=\frac{R}{V-b}$$So, for a real gas, the entropy change is greater than an ideal gas.

ADDENDUM FOR BOB D

At constant pressure, $$dS=\frac{C_p}{T}dT$$
and
$$dP=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_TdP=0$$So, $$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_P=-\frac{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T}{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V}$$Therefore, at constant pressure, $$dS=-\frac{C_p}{T}\frac{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T}{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V}dV$$For a van der Waals gas at constant pressure, this reduces to:  $$dS=\frac{C_p}{(V-b)}\left[1-\frac{2a(V-b)^2}{RTV^3}\right]dV$$

For a real gas, the relationship between the heat capacity at constant pressure and the heat capacity at constant volume is given by:
$$C_p=C_v+T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P=C_v-T\frac{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V^2}{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T}$$For the van der Waals model of a real gas, this reduces to:
$$C_p=C_v+R+R\frac{\xi}{1-\xi}$$where $$\xi=\frac{2a(V-b)^2}{RTV^3}$$For a van der Waals gas we can also show that the heat capacity at constant volume is equal to the ideal gas heat capacity at constant volume $C_v^{IG}$, independent of gas volume or pressures.  Therefore, $$C_p=C_p^{IG}+R\frac{\xi}{1-\xi}$$So for the van der Waals model, the heat capacity at constant volume is higher than the value in the ideal gas limit.

So for the van der Waals model at constant pressure, the variation of entropy with volume is given by combining previous equations to obtain:
$$dS=\frac{C_p^{IG}+R\frac{\xi}{1-\xi}}{(V-b)}\left[1-\xi\right]dV$$

Therefore, for the van der Waals model at constant pressure, this result indicates that the ratio of the real gas entropy change to that of an ideal gas can greater or less than unity, depending on the specific values of the parameters involved.

Comment: Hi Chet. You rigorously proved what I could only convey by intuition. Thumbs up 

Comment: Hi @BobD No offense Bob, but, if I read your answer correctly, you seemed to arrive at the opposite conclusion.

Comment: No offense ever taken. I realized it after rereading your answer. I'm sure you are correct and the math bears that out, but it goes against my intuition. If I add heat to an ideal gas to increase its volume it all goes to increasing its internal kinetic energy. If I add it to a real gas, I would think a fraction of it would increase its potential energy due to the van der Waals forces. Based on that I would think the entropy of the ideal gas would increase more. How is my intuition failing me?

Comment: Hi Chet. I'm looking at your equation again. You appear to be taking the partial derivative of entropy with respect to volume at constant temperature. Does  that mean you are assuming the increase in volume occurs at constant temperature (isothermal process)? I guess I was thinking of a constant pressure  addition of heat, so that the temperature of the gas increases  with volume. Again, how is my thinking wrong?

Comment: See my request to the OP for clarification.

Comment: @BobD I'm not really qualified to address most questions involving molecular arguments.  My expertise is mainly in continuum mechanics.

Comment: Understood. But does your equation assume the increase in volume occurs at constant temperature?

Comment: @BobD My interpretation was that the intent of the question was at constant temperature.  Would you like me to also provide an analysis if the volume changes at constant pressure.

Comment: Yes, please, if you don't mind. It will help me. Thanks!

Comment: @BobD See my addendum so far.

Comment: Thanks for all this work

Comment: @BobD See the completion of the analysis.

Comment: So in both cases the increase in entropy is greater for the real gas than the ideal gas, be it  a constant temperature or constant pressure process. I still can't see it intuitively, in particular for the constant pressure process. I would think that a greater increase in KE than PE for a given heat transfer for the ideal gas would be associated with higher entropy change for the ideal gas. But the math apparently proves  me wrong. I am going to file your analysis in my future use reference file. Thanks.

Comment: I came across the following: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/329513/entropy-of-an-ideal-gas-vs-entropy-of-a-non-ideal-gas Valerio concludes for a given V, T, P and N, the entropy of an ideal gas is higher. But that's not the same as saying it is greater when there is a change in V, and a statistical analysis was used.

Comment: @BobD I don't follow the analysis in the reference. Anyway, I'm changing the conclusion slightly for the case of constant pressure entropy change.  Depending on the values of the parameters involved, it seems like it can be greater or smaller.